# Searching for a sound snippet in audio files

Tags: windows-7, audio, mp3

I have several days' worth of recordings of a radio show, stored in a number of two-hour MP3 files.

I am looking for one specific song that I'm fairly sure is somewhere in these recordings. It's an old roots reggae song in a [toasted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deejaying) on variation. There is at least a 15-20 second snippet that is identical with the original song, which I have.

Is there any Open Source or affordable tool that allows me to search through the audio files for that snippet?

I can use Windows 7 and Linux.

> My specific issue has since been solved, but this is a deserving question on its own IMO. Adding a bounty to see whether anything else comes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technology you are looking for is called [Acoustic fingerprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint), defined as :

> An acoustic fingerprint is a condensed
>   digital summary, deterministically
>   generated from an audio signal, that
>   can be used to identify an audio
>   sample or quickly locate similar items
>   in an audio database.

There are many applications of it listed in the above Wikipedia link, but most are commercial.

Another list of freeware and commercial products are found in the article [AudioFingerprint](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/AudioFingerprint) in MusicBrainz, a user-maintained open community that collects and makes available to the public music metadata in the form of a relational database.

Some free and open-source projects from the list that you might examine :

[jHears](http://jhears.org/)
an acoustic fingerprinting framework.

[Acoustid](http://acoustid.org/)
open source project that aims to create a free database of audio fingerprints with mapping to the MusicBrainz metadata database and provide a web service for audio file identification using this database.

[libFooID](http://code.google.com/p/libfooid/)
an open source acoustic fingerprinting library.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the algorithm that Avery Wang developed for Shazam.  He's doing the same thing.  He stores fingerprints for each song in a library so they can be easily checked to see if there is a constellation of points that matches the ones from a snippet.

You can get his whitepaper and links to several other systems/ideas [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/9hos5/how_shazam_works_pdf/).

Comment: Cheers Ron! I went down the non-software route and managed to find the song on an ancient playlist, but this is very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I probed google and found this program [Similarity](http://www.music-similarity.com/). I can't say, if it is of any use. But you can download it and try it for free. If you buy it, it costs 20.00$ for one year, or 35$ for a lifetime. But i don't know if it can find music in so different files. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very interesting, but it doesn't seem to do searching for snippets, only real duplicates. Still, +1, this may help future askers with a similar question

Answer (score 0):

Sound-Similar Free (https://www.sound-similar.com) can be used to compare two WAV files and shows their perceptual similarity score in percentages. It can also be used to search for a sound snippet (the shorter one) in an audio file (the longer one).

[Sound-Similar Free](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wj5n.png)
[Spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXHW5.png)